# How to write Curl api example into PHP curl

Tags: php, api, curl, page-curl

I am using https://apptweak.io api,
they didn't mention PHP example in their code example...

please tell me, how to understand and write Curl API example into PHP curl

Here is simple "appteak.com" curl  example

```
curl -G https://api.apptweak.com/ios/applications/284993459/informations.json \
-d country=us \
-d language=en \
-d device=iphone \
-H "X-Apptweak-Key: my_api_key"
```

Here is other example

```
$ curl -H "X-Apptweak-Key: my_api_key" \
https://api.apptweak.com/android/applications/com.facebook.katana.json?country=be&language=nl
```

**How to write these curl in PHP?**

i did this in php, after google, but its not work for me.

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.apptweak.com/android/applications/com.facebook.katana.json?country=be&language=nl',
   // CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'X-Apptweak-Key' => "my_api_key",
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);


var_dump($resp ); //return false
```

Comment: are you sure you passed your API key?

Comment: -H is for headers. you should use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-Apptweak-Key','your key')`

Comment: Also you should remove CURLOPT_POST => 1 since it is GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find correct answer

```
$token = "my_api_key";
$url = "http://URL.com";

$options = array('http' => array(
    'header' => array("X-Apptweak-Key: $token"),
));
$context = stream_context_create($options);

$result = file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
```